# Weak solution of Laplace equation in $H^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

> Let $\Omega  = [0,1]$ and $f\in L^2(\Omega)$. Prove that the weak solution $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ of the Laplace
>   equation with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions $$-u''=f \text{ in } \Omega, \ \ \ u(0)=u(1)=0 \text{ on } \Omega$$ fulfills $u\in H^2(\Omega)$.

I was thinking $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ implies $u,u' \in L^2$, and $f\in L^2$  implies  $u''\in L^2$ if $u$ is a solution. But I think I need to use the definition of weak derivative somehow to show the weak second derivative exists.

Comment: You need to show that $u'$ has a weak derivative in $L^2$. Write down the definition of weak derivative and weak solution and stare at it for 5 minutes if necessary. It's really just a definition chase.

Comment: $-f$ is the weak derivative of $u'$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.